# PHP how to get the $http.defaults.headers.common['X-Token'] which defined in the angualrJS?

Tags: php, ajax, angularjs, http-headers

I have set $http.defaults.headers.common['X-Token'] to be some value in the AngularJS, but in the chrome debug tools, I can only see the x-token in the Access-Control-Request-Headers, can't see the specific value I set to the x-token. And in the PHP side, how to get the value in $http.defaults.headers.common['X-Token']?

```
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:zh-CN,zh;q=0.8
Access-Control-Request-Headers:accept, x-token123, x-token
Access-Control-Request-Method:GET
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Host:192.168.1.6
Origin:http://localhost:9000
Pragma:no-cache
Referer:http://localhost:9000/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2288.6 Safari/537.36
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the header of which you can't see value in dev tools, similar to `User-Token` in my plunker

http://plnkr.co/edit/36Dq6UXgyeMEXOzycrua?p=preview

```
app.config(function ( $httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['User-Token'] = 'finding???';
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/json; charset=utf-8';
});
```

and to get headers you can use `getallheaders()` which returns array

#### php

```
echo json_encode(getallheaders());
```